# Azure Table Designer

Tags: azure

I have an Azure test site and I'm attempting to hook it up to an Azure SQL database.  I used the Azure portal to create a new database.  Since the database was successfully created, I then opened SSMS 2012 and connected to the server and database.  I expected to be able to create new tables, etc. through SSMS using the standard Create Table GUI (the one that lets you enter the column name, Identity, data type, etc. in grid format), but SSMS 2012 doesn't seem to have a table design window.  Am I missing something?  Is there an OOB release for this?  I'm running VS 2012 Ultimate, SSMS 2012 and I already have the VS2012 Azure SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the online portal? The same portal you used to create the database allows you to build tables using a grid format as you are describing. Just click on the Design button at the bottom left, then click on New Table at the bottom and off you go. You can also create indexes, foreign keys and so forth.

Comment: As crazy as it sounds, this might be the best solution, unless you're used to working in DDL

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have a look on the SQL Server Data Tool (SSDT) which should be includes in SQL Server 2012. Not sure if it's included in Express but once you installed SQL 2012 you will find a new window in Visual Studio 2012 where you can design your Azure SQL Database in GUI.

I have a blog about this feature but I think it became more simple to install and use.
http://blogs.shaunxu.me/archive/2012/04/28/ssdt-ndash-makes-sql-azure-development-easy.aspx